# Is this (char*)&x cast's behaviour well-defined?

Tags: c, string, casting, character

While writing some C code, I came across a little problem where I had to convert a character into a "string" (some memory chunk the beginning of which is given by a `char*` pointer).

The idea is that if some `sourcestr` pointer is set (not `NULL`), then I should use it as my "final string", otherwise I should convert a given `charcode` into the first character of another array, and use it instead.

For the purposes of this question, we'll assume that the types of the variables cannot be changed beforehand. In other words, I can't just store my `charcode` as a `const char*` instead of an `int`.

Because I tend to be lazy, I thought to myself : "hey, couldn't I just use the character's address and treat that pointer as a string?". Here's a little snippet of what I wrote *(don't smash my head against the wall just yet!)* :

```
int charcode    = FOO;   /* Assume this is always valid ASCII. */

char* sourcestr = "BAR"; /* Case #1 */
char* sourcestr = NULL;  /* Case #2 */

char* finalstr  = sourcestr ? sourcestr : (char*)&charcode;
```

Now of course I tried it, and as I expected, it does work. Even with a few warning flags, the compiler is still happy. However, I have this weird feeling that this is actually undefined behaviour, and that I just shouldn't be doing it.

The reason why I think this way is because `char*` arrays need to be null-terminated in order to be printed properly as strings (and I want mine to be!). Yet, I have no certainty that the value at `&charcode + 1` will be zero, hence I might end up with some buffer overflow madness.

**Is there an actual reason why it does work properly, or have I just been lucky to get zeroes in the right places when I tried?**

*(Note that I'm not looking for other ways to achieve the conversion. I could simply use a `char tmp[2] = {0}` variable, and put my character at index 0. I could also use something like `sprintf` or `snprintf`, provided I'm careful enough with buffer overflows. There's a myriad of ways to do this, I'm just interested in the behaviour of this particular cast operation.)*

*Edit:* I've seen a few people call this hackery, and let's be clear: I completely agree with you. I'm not enough of a masochist to actual do this in released code. This is just me getting curious ;)

Comment: In case 2, if you are printing that pointer as a string then no, it isn't defined.

Comment: `char *` is a pointer. C does not have a string type. Compiler warning exist for good reasons. Pay heed to them.

Comment: In and of itself thats not UB, however when you treat it like a string (like printing it with printf or alike) then it becomes UB

Comment: @Olaf I'm just calling it a string because I'll use `%s` to print it, of course it's not actually a "string" as we understand it in higher-level languages. As it so happens, compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` yields absolutely no warning with my `gcc`, hence the question :)

Comment: This is read by others, too. See the questions how much confusion there is already about pointers, arrays and "strings" in C. If you know better, don't be lax!

Comment: @Olaf The question has been edited, thank you for you comments then ;) If anyone sees a clearer way to put things, I'll be happy to take an edit.

Comment: If that is for some default, why not just e.g. `finalstr = "default string"` or `char charcode[] = "default string"`? Why that UB-prone hack with an `int` variable?

Comment: @Olaf I'm not really looking for workarounds, I just came across this and got curious. In my particular case, the integer isn't a constant (or a default), so that doesn't apply: I'll of course use a cleaner solution. I just simplified it here, to focus on the possible UB. *(I'll accept an answer later today, I don't like accepting answers right away, even though those I got so far are very interesting :p)*

Comment: @JohnWHSmith *just calling it a string because I'll use %s to print it, of course it's not actually a "string" as we understand it in higher-level languages. As it so happens, compiling with -Wall -Wextra yields absolutely no warning with my gcc, hence the question :) –* See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely undefined behavior for the following reasons:

1. Less probable, but to consider when strictly referencing to the standards: you can't assume the sizeof int on the machine/system where code will be compiled
2. As above you can't assume the codeset. E.g. what happen on an EBCDIC machine/system?
3. Easy to say that your machine has a little endian processor. **On big endian machines the code fails** due to big-endian memory layout.
4. Because on many systems `char` is a signed integer, as is `int`, when your char is a negative value (i.e. `char>127` on machines having 8bits `char`), **it could fail due to sign extension** if you assign the value as in the code below

code:

```
char ch = FOO;
int charcode = ch;
```

P.S. About the point 3: your string **will be indeed NULL terminated in a little endian machine having `sizeof(int)>sizeof(char)` and `char` having a positive value**, because the MSB of int will be 0 and the memory layout for such endianess is LSB-MSB (LSB first).

Comment: Why would it make a difference if the encoding were EBCDIC? As long as the original source for FOO was a character literal or a character read as with fgetc, it should be fine.

Comment: @rici just because some symbols that in ascii are apositive integer in EBCDIC can be negative. Maybe this is an excess of caution :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your code is well-defined as you can always cast to `char*`. But some issues:

1. Note that `"BAR"` is a `const char*` literal - so don't attempt to modify the contents. That *would* be undefined.
2. Don't attempt to use `(char*)&charcode` as a parameter to any of the string functions in the C standard library. It will **not** be null-terminated. So in that sense, you **cannot** treat it as a string.
3. Pointer arithmetic on `(char*)&charcode` *will* be valid up to and including one past the scalar `charcode`. But **don't** attempt to *dereference* any pointer beyond `charcode` itself. The range of `n` for which the expression `(char*)&charcode + n` is valid depends on `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

The cast and assignment, `char* finalstr = (char*)&charcode;` is defined.

Printing `finalstr` with printf as a string, `%s`, if it points to `charcode` is undefined behavior.

Rather than resorting to hackery and hiding string in a type `int`, convert the values stored in the integer to a string using a chosen conversion function. One possible example is:

```
char str[32] = { 0 };
snprintf( str , 32 , "%d" , charcode );
char* finalstr = sourcestr ? sourcestr : str;
```

or use whatever other (defined!) conversion you like.

Comment: Strictly speaking printing is UB only if value doesn't contain zero byte. If it does have zero bytes, it's implementation defined whether it's UB. For example `charcode` value `'A'` would be OK on little-endian system with ASCII charset.

Comment: @user694733 It wouldn't be. Specifier %s must receive a string, i.e. an array of `character type`, which type `int` is not , otherwise the behavior is undefined. See 7.21.6.1. paragraph 8.and 9 (Even though int consists of bytes it is not an array of character type.)

Comment: @2501: C11 draft standard `6.5 Expressions, Section 7 An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:[...]— a character type.`. You can treat *everything* as an array of `char`. Byte-order will be implementation-dependent, but it's not *undefined*, as long as there is null-termination.

Comment: I was going to nitpick further, that it requires pointer, not array. But it seems that standard does indeed mention array: *"... the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of __an array of character type__."* So it seems you're right. It works on practical systems, but I do agree that this is hackery.

Comment: at EOF: Irrelevant. We aren't arguing that you cannot point to it, but that you cannot print it with printf and family. The section I quoted is clear. Printing with %s requires an array of character type. Int is of int type, and not an array of character type, and it never can be.

Answer (score 2):

Like other said it happens to work because the internal representation of an int on your machine is little endian and your char is smaller than an int. Also the ascii value of your character is either below 128 or you have unsigned chars (otherwise there would be sign extension). This means that the value of the character is in the lower byte(s) of the representation of the int and the rest of the int will be all zeroes (assuming any normal representation of an int). You're not "lucky", you have a pretty normal machine.

It is also completely undefined behavior to give that char pointer to any function that expects a string. You might get away with it now but the compiler is free to optimize that to something completely different.

For example if you do a `printf` just after that assignment, the compiler is free to assume that you'll always pass a valid string to `printf` which means that the check for `sourcestr` being NULL is unnecessary because if `sourcestr` was NULL `printf` would be called with something that isn't a string and the compiler is free to assume that undefined behavior never happens. Which means that any check of `sourcestr` being NULL before or after that assignment are unnecessary because the compiler already knows it isn't NULL. This assumption is allowed to spread to everywhere in your code.

This was rarely a thing to worry about and you could get away with tricks uglier than this until a decade ago or so when compiler writers started an arms race about how much they can follow the C standard to the letter to get away with more and more brutal optimizations. Today compilers are getting more and more aggressive and while the optimization I speculated about probably doesn't exist yet, if a compiler person sees this, they'll probably implement it just because they can.